# How to send automated Push notification using Pushwoosh in android

Tags: android, json, push-notification, pushwoosh

I have asked this question before but no answer. I successfully integrated Pushwoosh into my android application and their service has been wonderful, but now I want to make it automated because in one of the section in my app, there is a blog that is constantly updated using a Json Webservice. What I want to achieve is this, I want a push notification sent to users on the app, when there is an update from the Json web-service. Is there an online tutorial on this and how to achieve this, I would prefer if its very explanatory. I have searched online for a while now and i have been unable to come up with anything meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt from [Pushwoosh pricing site](http://www.pushwoosh.com/pricing/) that we need to pay minimum 39Euros for subscription and only then we get access for RemoteAPI with which we can push data from our server. This facility is not available for free version. In case you have implemented this, kindly share some steps for the same